# Question about session management in servlet jsp

Tags: jakarta-ee, session, jsp

I'm currently developing a middle level web-app in J2EE using servlets and JSP. It is just like a Content Management System. My website is working very similar according to my needs, but there are some *Questions* about *the best practices and the bad practices* for using **MVC** in J2EE.

Code for user to log-in to app is:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.admin}">
    <a href="/context/controller?action=add-content"> + Add a Content</a>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <a href="/context/controller?action=log-in"> Admin Login</a>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Java code in controller servlet is:

```
if (userDAO.isUser(request.getParameter("uname"), request.getParameter("upass"))) {             
    request.getSession().setAttribute("admin", request.getParameter("uname"));  
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/admin.jsp").forward(request, response);
} else {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("admin", "");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/content.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

For log-out:

```
<a href="/context/controller?action=log-out">Logout</a>
```

Java code in controller servlet is:

```
if (action != null && action.equals("log-out")) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session != null){
            session.invalidate();
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(
                request, response);
    }
```

I want to know is above logic for log-in, log-out and session management is correct?

And I'm also unable to preventing the user go back to secure page after he is logged-out, how can I set that?

Comment: Avoid going back is not an option. All browsers allow this or the user can retype the URL or go by searching the history. You MUST consider the user WILL always go back or access direct pages using history. So, be prepared for this in your controller and send the user for his right place. LONG LIVE THE USERS!

Answer (score 0):

One glaring error I can see right off the bat is that every login attempt that's not recognised as a regular user is allowed to log in as an admin.
I seriously doubt that's what you want, you'd want those logins denied and an error displayed...
And you'd probably want to set up your system so admins are regular users as well.

So you'd get something like:
if (login == success) then if (login == admin) then login_as_admin else login_as_user else deny_login_with_error